# How do I increase the resolution of BlueStacks?

Tags: bluestacks, screen-resolution

Presently, my BlueStacks appears slightly blurry. By blurry, I mean 'not sharp'. 
Compare BlueStacks with my desktop:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>**BlueStacks** (Click image to enlarge)</sup>

The difference is subtle, but I don't like it. I think it's got something to do with the resolution. How do I increase it so that the items in BlueStacks appear sharp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the Resolution of BlueStack:

- Open ‘regedit': Start->Run->regedit
- Navigate to: `'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/BlueStacks/Guests/Android/FrameBuffer/0/’`
- Double click the value ‘GuestHeight’
- Change Base to Decimal
- Input your desired Height resolution
- Double click the value ‘GuestWidth’
- Change Base to Decimal
- Input your desired Height resolution
- Restart your PC, Open BlueStack [It will open up with New Resolution.]

Check this Link to work Around :

http://www.techcrises.com/how-to/how-to-change-bluestacks-resolution-in-windows-fixed/

Comment: I set it to 1366x768. My max display resolution is also the same. But still it appears the same. I even restarted my PC.

Comment: I used an app and saw that this really changes the resolution. It must be a problem with BlueStacks rendering. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Well ! That's Great !! Farhan !!

Comment: how about on macOSX?

Answer (score 2):

Bluestacks now has built-in options for increasing resolution and DPI, which can reduce blurriness. By default, neither of these are maxed.

See https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003116443-How-can-I-customize-BlueStacks-3-resolution-and-DPI-

[image]