# developed apk installed in bluestacks lost lower part

Tags: applications, screen, android-emulator, bluestacks, screen-resolution

I installed an app-invenetor2 developed app, then installed it to bluestacks.
I cannot see the lower part of the app. I've 
tried to adjust the resolution of bluestacks using methods suggested by [How do I increase the resolution of BlueStacks?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/128727/how-do-i-increase-the-resolution-of-bluestacks), especially the height from 400 to 1800. But it's failed.
Although the height of bluestacks window is increased, the lower part of installed app didn't appear.
How to see that lower part of the app?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Lower part just disappear. Even I set the screen to be Portrait type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried it out. Just clicked "Change app size" on the left of BlueStacks to turn Tablet screen(Landscape) to Smartphone screen(Portrait), and it's done.